# List of Rows from Data Frames as Vector in R

Tags: r, list, dataframe, row, atomic

How can I convert rows into vectors in a list across multiple data frames?
I've been having the issue that after converting my rows into list form using:

```
pck <- list(NB[1,],NY[1,],AZ[1,],TB[1,])
```

I get the error

```
Error in sort.int(x, na.last = na.last, decreasing = decreasing, ...) : 
  'x' must be atomic
```

when I view my list `pck` I see:

```
> pck
[[1]]
         V1        V2       V3      V4
1 0.6190389 0.9105718 2.020711 1.99928

[[2]]
         V1        V2       V3      V4
1 0.6190389 0.9105718 2.020711 1.99928

[[3]]
        V1       V2       V3       V4
1 2.286501 1.395356 1.544924 1.435426

[[4]]
         V1       V2       V3       V4
1 0.9035451 1.637073 2.830873 4.209193
```

How can I convert my list to a set of atomic vectors such that I can use functions like `boxplot`? That is, how can I most simply coerce `pck` into a form like this:

```
> pck
[[1]]
[1] 0.6190389 0.9105718 2.020711 1.99928

[[2]]
[1] 0.6190389 0.9105718 2.020711 1.99928

[[3]]
[1] 2.286501 1.395356 1.544924 1.435426

[[4]]
[1] 0.9035451 1.637073 2.830873 4.209193
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
pck <- lapply(pck, unlist, use.names = F)
```